# how to fetch lvm mount point (generic)

Tags: mount, lvm

I need to write a script that will check whether an LVM exists on the system or not.
If an LVM exists, then it will perform certain steps else it will do other steps.

My issue here is how to find a generic approach to find the lvm name and its mount point.
I have tried by fetching the lv name and vg name from lvdisplay command and then grep it from mount.

```
LV_Name=`sudo lvdisplay | sed -n '3,4p' | sed -n '1p' | awk '{print $3}'`
VG_Name=`sudo lvdisplay | sed -n '3,4p' | sed -n '2p' | awk '{print $3}'`
echo -e "VG_Name is $VG_Name. \nLV_Name is $LV_Name".
lv_device_name=`echo $VG_Name-$LV_Name`
echo "LVM device name is $lv_device_name"
mount_point=`mount | grep $lv_device_name | awk '{print $3}'`
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "$mount_point is the mount point for $lv_device_name"
    else
    echo "No LVM found"
fi
```

but now the problem is that this is not generic irrespective of *nix platform.

This is Ubuntu14.04 specific script and here lvm mount point is `/mnt/lvm` with lv name is `lvm_testing-lvnamefortest`.

On Debian machine the same is `/dev/mapper/deb--all--lvm01-usr` on `/usr`
, however the lvm name returned from above command is `deb-all-lvm01-usr`.

Is there any generic command or steps which will work on all platforms (like RHEL, CentOS, Ubuntu, Debian etc.)?

Comment: considering LVM volume names can be defined by the administrator, my answer would be NO. If you let everything to go by default naming conventions, probably you can get away with writing a script to parse the output but again as far as I know LVM commands do not have a internal switch to output in a uniform format regardless of platform.

Comment: An LVM (ie. the manager) can exists without any PVs/VGs/LVs being created. You are testing the wrong thing, or asking the wrong question.

Comment: `lsblk` or `findmnt` might mark lvm mounts. I don't have a means to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You script is far more complicated than it needs to be and has a few problems:

1. You use backticks rather than `$()`.
2. Your script ignores all but the first logical volume it finds.
3. You assume that lack of a mount-point for an lvpath means that there
   are no logical volumes.  This assumption is just plain wrong.
4. both `lvs` and `lvdisplay` already tell you the device name in LV Path, there's no need to make any assumptions or guesses about how it might be named.
5. `lvs` has far more flexible output options than either `lvdisplay` or `vgdisplay`.

Try something more like this instead:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

lvcount=0

while read lvname vgname lvpath ; do
    lvcount=$((lvcount+1))

    printf "VG_Name is %s.\nLV_Name is %s.\n" "$vgname" "$lvname"

    echo "LVM Device name is $lvpath"

    mp=$(mount | grep "$lvpath" | awk '{print $3}')
    if [ -n "$mp" ] ; then
        echo "$mp is the mount point for $lvpath"
    else
        echo "$lvpath is not mounted."
    fi
    echo
done < <(lvs --no-headings -o lv_name,vg_name,lv_path)

echo "Found $lvcount logical volumes."
```

Comment: `lvs -o lv_path` will show "friendly" paths like `/dev/centos_foo/root` but `mount` will show "mapper" names like `/dev/mapper/centos_foo-root`, and thus trick your script into thinking it is not mounted.